Why I can't change the prompt in VSCode's terminal?
I am trying to change the prompt in my VSCode's terminal.
My OS is MacOS Monterey 12.6.
I use the zsh and I change the PS1 in .zprofile,such like this.

Then I use echo to test.The others can work except PS1.

How to change the prompt?Is there any simple way?

Please don’t put text (the .zprofile contents) in an image. Instead, put it in a code block.

Oh,sry,it's my fault.

The default shell in MacOS is usually zsh, but it could also be bash.
In your case, it appears to be zshrc:
For zshrc:
vim ~/.zshrc

Modify the prompt:
export PROMPT='%F{blue}%n%f@%F{green}%m%f %F{yellow}%1~%f %# '

Enable the change:
source ~/.zshrc 

But, if you have bash, edit .bash_profile or .bashrc in your home directory:
vim ~/.bash_profile

Or
vim ~/.bashrc

Modify the prompt:
export PS1='\u@\h \w \$ '

Apply the change:
source ~/.bash_profile

or
source ~/.bashrc

That should do it!

Thank you very much.I write PS1 in .zshrc and it works now.

A comprehensive guide can be found at https://www.makeuseof.com/customize-zsh-prompt-macos-terminal/ . You're welcome!
